# Debugging Custom Control Not Hitting Breakpoint

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging

Right, can't seem to find this on SO, I'm sure it must have been asked before, anyway....

Simply put, I am creating a new custom control from scratch and I have a method:

```
private void Foo()
```

I am calling straight from the constructor.  I have put a breakpoint in Foo() but the debugger never halts at this breakpoint, it just shows the Test Container:

[image]

Anyone know how to make the debugger stop at the breakpoint without going straight to the Test Container dialog.

---

**CODE**

**Behind the control:**

```
namespace AreaPickerDotNet
{
    public partial class AreaPickerDotNet : UserControl
    {

        Assembly _assem;

        public AreaPickerDotNet()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            _assem =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            Foo();
        }


        private void Foo()
        {

            try
            {
                StreamReader _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assem.GetManifestResourceStream("foo.txt"));
                MessageBox.Show(_textStreamReader.GetHashCode().ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Designer Code:**

```
namespace AreaPickerDotNet
{
    partial class AreaPickerDotNet
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)

        {
           if (disposing && (components != null))
           {
              components.Dispose();
           }
           base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

       #region Component Designer generated code

       /// <summary>
       /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
       /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
       /// </summary>
       private void InitializeComponent()
       {
          this.SuspendLayout();
          // 
          // AreaPickerDotNet
          // 
          this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
          this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
          this.Name = "AreaPickerDotNet";
          this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(291, 259);
          this.ResumeLayout(false);

       }

       #endregion
   }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line where you create the control, and step manually (F11), does it still skip it?

Comment: Could you try a BUILD > Clean Solution and re-launch the debugger. Are other breakpoints getting hit?

Comment: Tried both suggestions - no break point gets hit, not even in the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging? Seriously, this is my favorite error - try to hit breakpoint in Release mode.

Comment: Have you tried to set an exception in your code? Does it occurs during application run?

Comment: Looks like you're using a designer, does the UserControl have a Designer attribute on it that may be used to render the preview? Can you share the class definition (and any attributes that are set on it), the constructor(s) and the method `foo` with us?

Comment: @VMAtm Breakpoint not hit in "Release" mode.

Comment: @VMAtm No exception raised during running the code so never hit the breakpoint with try/catch.

Comment: @jessehouwing have put the code in the question as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've developed the UI Control, but didn't add it to your main Form.

Do you actually call `AreaPickerDotNet()` method from anythere in your application? I think that you need to add your UI Control to your Form via designer or from code directly.

---

**Update:**
After your comment I stopped to understand your question.

1. You can't debug the Library project, so you have a project into your solution which is being run during debug.
2. If your code implements a custom UI control, you can't just debug it - to run the code you **have to** add the control manually via code or designer on some WinForm in your application.
3. The fact you've added a reference to your UI control library isn't enough to run the control - it's simply a reference, which is useless until you add the control to your WinForms.

Comment: No, I'm just creating a custom control in a project type: Windows Form Control Library.  After which I should be able to distriubte and add the control to any winforms project I choose.

Comment: @Vidar Updated the answer. I think you just don't fully understand the UI control needs for.

Comment: Yep - I created a seperate winforms project in the same solution as the controls library, dropped the control on the form and was able to debug.  Thanks, for clearing that one up :)